# Install packages from PYPI in Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi3, pypi

I want to install a precompiled version of OpenCV 3.4.2 in the Raspberry using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install pip3
sudo pip3 install opencv-python
```

But it failed and the error message was: *"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for opencv-python"*

Then tried the following commands but the result was the same:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip install opencv-python
```

I had not problems installing it on my PC with ubuntu 16 using the same commands. This is the page im using for reference https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

I'm using Raspbian Jessie Lite, Python 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The list of downloadable files](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files) for opencv includes binary wheels for many Python versions but for limited set of architectures: MacOSX on Intel, Linux on Intel 32 and 64 bits, Windows on Intel 32 and 64 bits. Raspberry Pi processors absent and there is no source code so `pip` cannot compile it.

The [FAQ](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#frequently-asked-questions) recommends to look up Pi wheels at https://www.piwheels.org/.

Comment: I should have read the whole page more carefully, all the information was there. Thank you.